# Need the last day of the current date to be passed in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass date to a method in my angular application in shortdate format but the day needs to be last day of the month. How do I do that

This is what I have done

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';

 this.allocationsComponent.getAllocationsDetails(formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en'));
```

The result is

```
2019/04/02
```

Comment: can you make an example?

Comment: Sorry, how is '2019/04/02' the last day of the month? Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var today = new Date();
var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);
this.allocationsComponent.getAllocationsDetails(formatDate(lastDayOfMonth, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `Date` has an interesting quirk: The 0th day of a month is the last day of the previous month:

```
> var d=new Date();
Tue Apr 02 2019 14:40:02
> d.setDate(0);
Sun Mar 31 2019 14:40:02
```

Answer (score 0):

simple methods and Reduced/single line of code

```
this.allocationsComponent.getAllocationsDetails(formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0)), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en'));
```